# Criteria in hibernate 5.2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to know why the following piece of code worked for me using eclipseLink and not using Hibernate 5.2

```
javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

this code is the implementation of a generic findAll() method that returns all rows of an entity. When I switch this implementation to one less generic, it's work.

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("from Answers");
return query.getResultList();
```

So, why criteria doesn't work for me?

Ps.: I want to use max of JPA as possible.

EDIT: here is the log printed in the server side.

```
ago 13, 2017 5:16:24 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: testerHPU
    ...]
ago 13, 2017 5:16:24 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
ago 13, 2017 5:16:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
ago 13, 2017 5:16:24 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
ago 13, 2017 5:16:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
ago 13, 2017 5:16:26 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste]
ago 13, 2017 5:16:26 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
ago 13, 2017 5:16:26 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
ago 13, 2017 5:16:26 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
ago 13, 2017 5:16:27 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
ago 13, 2017 5:16:29 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Comment: what is the error you getting?

Comment: my REST Client receive http response status 500. In the serve that host the rest web services no one error is launched.

Comment: I edited the post, Have anyone way to get more detailed errors info?

Comment: This is not the error but the boot-up of Spring. Have you ensured (via debugging at least) that it's reaching the Hibernate Criteria bit.

Comment: Man!! I found the error, I was passing the wrong package to create the entityClass variable and it was capturing the DAO class instead the Entity class, fixing it is all working now! Thanks.